# How to use Google analytics in a Xamarin project?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-analytics

I would like to use Google Analytics in my Xamarin project, but I always find articles showing how to use it with Firebase. Is that the only possibility? Can I use just Goggle Analytics without Firebase, as I use for example in my Angular project?

Answer (score 1):

While the link to the repo [google-analytics-dotnet-sdk](https://github.com/LindaLawton/google-analytics-dotnet-sdk) created by me supplied by another another answer to this question.

Will work if you are using Universal analytics.   It will not send hits to GA4. I have been working on a version for Ga4 but set aside while i wait for the Measurement protocol for Ga4 to be completed.

Currently the measurement protocol for GA4 does not allow for recreating hits similar to what is sent by the standard google analytics sdks for web and mobile.

Which means that you cant exactly recreate the same events.

[Measurement Protocol (Google Analytics 4)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4)  I guess what I am saying is that if your goal is to recreate similar hits as firebase sends then your not going to be able to.  We need to wait for them to open up for more of the Measurement protocol.

This is the current status of it.

[GoogleAnalytics.Ga4-Dotnet.Sdk - Beta](https://github.com/DAIMTO/GoogleAnalytics.Ga4.Dotnet.Sdk)